# How to include username of the invoiced/shipped user in order comment history?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I'm using magento `CE 1.7`. I want to show the order invoiced or shipped person's username to be appear with the comment history. I override the `Mage_Sales_OrderController` to append the username in `addCommentAction(){..}` . But it works only when the user adds comments not when create / invoice the order. 
Please any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. Here's the solution. I have overridden  `Mage_Sales_Model_Order`

```
class Add_OrderComment_Model_Order extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order 
{

    public function addStatusHistoryComment($comment, $status = false)
    {
        if(Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isLoggedIn())
        {
            // Getting admin username.
            $user = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
            $username = $user->getUser()->getUsername();
            $append = " <strong>(Updated by : ".$username.")</strong>";
        }
        else 
        {
            $append = "";
        }
        if (false === $status) {
            $status = $this->getStatus();
        } elseif (true === $status) {
            $status = $this->getConfig()->getStateDefaultStatus($this->getState());
        } else {
            $this->setStatus($status);
        }
        $history = Mage::getModel('sales/order_status_history')
            ->setStatus($status)
            ->setComment($comment.$append)
            ->setEntityName($this->_historyEntityName);
        $this->addStatusHistory($history);
        return $history;
    }

}
```